# TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response tuple. The tuple must have the form (body, status, headers), (body, status),

Tags: python, mysql, flask, fetchall

[This is the pic of Mysql DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1rDg.png)[Here is the code] https://i.stack.imgur.com/muX0s.png

after this i am expecting Mathew to be the output but error is coming
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muX0s.png) https://i.stack.imgur.com/taUgq.png

Comment: Please do not put code in images, please include it as text within the question

Answer (score 2):

users is a list of tuples. In your image, you show that the database contains just one field, for username.

Thus when you do `users[0]`, this returns a tuple of size 1: `('Matthew')` which is not a valid response.

To return Matthew, you should `return users[0][0]`: the first `[0]` to fetch the first row from your query and the second `[0]` to fetch the first field (username) from that row.

Edit: Updated my answer to match OP's SQL schema

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1rDg.png      This is the pic oF mysql DB

Comment: This worked for me, I going through the same issue for the same code, I got this from a Udemy course, Mathew should be my result, however I changed it to [0][0] not [0][0]:[0], it worked